# create view depending on key and date (oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

I will try to explain my requirement, it is a little bit complicated.

I would like to store messages with keys regarding dates. 
For example for `date1`, which is valid from `dateX` and `dateY`, I would like to store message `text1` with `key 1`
and for `date2`, which is valid from `dateX2` and `dateY2`, I would like to store message `text2` also with `key 1` and so on.

For this reason, I have created the following table with the composite key (id and valid_from)

```
messages_table:
ID msg valid_from valid_to
1  text1 01.01.2000 31.12.2001
1  text2 01.01.2002 31.12.2003
2  text3 01.01.2000 31.12.2001
2  text4 01.01.2002 31.12.2003
3  text5 31.12.2001 31.12.2001
3  text6 01.01.2002 31.12.2003
..
...
100 ..........
```

Now I would like to create a view table on this messages_table, which displays appropriate text message depending on valid_from date and ID. 
for selecting a text message depending on valid_from, I use something like this where valid_from between 01.01.1999 and 01.02.2000, this works. 
since there are a lot of messages (from 1 to 100), I need to limit the view rows rows using the ID, something like this where ID in (1,2,3), this is also working.

the view looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW messages_view(id, msg)
AS
  SELECT id,
    id
    || ' '
    || msg
  FROM messages_table
  WHERE java_function.get_date BETWEEN valid_from AND valid_to
  AND id IN (1,2,22,32);
```

this will create view with messages between valid_from and valid_to and keys which are in (1,2,22,32).

Now the issue/requirement is that I need to select the rows depending on the given `date`. Example, for date between `01.01.2000 and 31.12.2001`, I would need to select keys in let's say `(1,3,55)` and when `date` is 
between `01.01.2002 and 31.12.2003`, I need to select keys in `(1,20,30)`

How to adjust the view to fulfill this requirement?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a separate table to map the keys to the respective dates and use the same in the select query of the view(either join or exists sub query).

Regards.

Comment: Any example? may be there is a better way to fulfill this requirement without creating further table?

Comment: If you don't keep a separate mapping then each time you want to modify the date and key mapping you have to modify the view and recreate it. so it would be better if you make the mapping independent of the view so as and when the mapping is changed then you don't need to recreate the view. it will refresh accordingly.